# How to optimize SQL Server query that might be doing parameter sniffing

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016, index-tuning

This simplified query on SQL 2017 takes 40+ sec to complete, I suspect its parameter sniffing issue, but not 100% sure.

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT
    T.[TicketRecId]
    , T.[Title]
FROM dbo.Ticket T
INNER JOIN [dbo].[State] S  
    ON S.[StateRecId] = T.[StateRecId]  
INNER JOIN [dbo].[StateType] ST  
    ON S.[StateTypeRecId] = ST.StateTypeRecId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Board] B  
    ON B.[BoardRecId] = T.[BoardRecId]  
WHERE 1=1
    AND ST.[Name] NOT IN (''Closed'',''Canceled'')
    AND T.BoardRecId IN (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@BoardRecId, '',''))
    --AND T.BoardRecId = @BoardRecId2
    --AND T.BoardRecId = 17
ORDER BY T.[TicketRecId] ASC
OFFSET (@PageNo - 1) * @PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
',N'@PageNo int,@PageSize int,@TeamRecId int,@BoardRecId VARCHAR(2),@BoardRecId2 INT'
    ,@PageNo=1,@PageSize=50,@TeamRecId=4,@BoardRecId ='17',@BoardRecId2=17
```

- This query returns 15 rows out of 1.7mil rows in `dbo.Ticket` table
- Tables `State`, `StateType`, `Board` are really small, 400, 20, 35 rows respectively
- In the `WHERE` clause, if I swap the `IN` filter to use `=` for `T.BoardRecId`, it completes in 7 sec
- Removing the `OFFSET FETCH`, original query completes in 13 sec, and previous query completes in 1 sec
- If I set parameter value `@BoardRecId='14'`, duration improves (majority of table contains rows with this value)
- Tried updating stats with fullscan for the table, no change in performance
- Tried creating varying indexes, perf did not improve
- Tried `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` inside the `sp_executesql` did not help
- Did not try rebuilding indexes yet as this has to be done during maintenance hours
- Tried replacing `dbo.Split` with a table variable and/or temp table, no improvement

I need ability to support multiple `BoardRecIds`, which is the reason behind the `dbo.Split` function, all it does is breaking out a comma separated string to be used inside an `IN` clause.

The schema is much larger in terms of columns, so trying to simplify it, note that the joined columns all have indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE [Support].[Ticket] (
    [TicketRecId]             BIGINT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BoardRecId]              INT                NOT NULL,
    [StateRecId]              INT                NOT NULL,
    [Title]                   VARCHAR (250)      NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted]               BIT        NOT NULL,
    [IsTemplate]              BIT        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Ticket_TicketRecId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TicketRecId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Ticket_BoardRecId] FOREIGN KEY ([BoardRecId]) REFERENCES [Support].[Board] ([BoardRecId]),
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc_Ticket_BoardRecIdStateRecIdIsDeletedIsTemplate_Include]
ON [Support].[Ticket] ([BoardRecId],[StateRecId],[IsDeleted],[IsTemplate],)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc_Ticket_BoardRecId_IsDeleted_IsTemplate_Includes]
ON [Support].[Ticket] ([BoardRecId], [IsDeleted], [IsTemplate], [ContactRecId], [ContactSourceRecId])
INCLUDE ([StateRecId]);
GO

CREATE TABLE [Support].[Ticket] (
    [TicketRecId]             BIGINT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BoardRecId]              INT                NOT NULL,
    [StateRecId]              INT                NOT NULL,
    [Title]                   VARCHAR (250)      NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted]               BIT        NOT NULL,
    [IsTemplate]              BIT        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Ticket_TicketRecId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TicketRecId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Ticket_BoardRecId] FOREIGN KEY ([BoardRecId]) REFERENCES [Support].[Board] ([BoardRecId]),
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc_Ticket_BoardRecIdStateRecIdIsDeletedIsTemplate_Include]
ON [Support].[Ticket] ([BoardRecId],[StateRecId],[IsDeleted],[IsTemplate],)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc_Ticket_BoardRecId_IsDeleted_IsTemplate_Includes]
ON [Support].[Ticket] ([BoardRecId], [IsDeleted], [IsTemplate], [ContactRecId], [ContactSourceRecId])
INCLUDE ([StateRecId]);
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[State] (
    [StateRecId]     INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BoardRecId]     INT                NOT NULL,
    [StateTypeRecId] INT                NOT NULL,
    [Name]           VARCHAR (50)       NOT NULL,
    [SortOrder]      SMALLINT           NOT NULL,
    [IsDefault]      BIT                NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted]      BIT                DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_State_StateRecId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StateRecId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_State_BoardRecId] FOREIGN KEY ([BoardRecId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Board] ([BoardRecId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_State_StateTypeRecId] FOREIGN KEY ([StateTypeRecId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[StateType] ([StateTypeRecId]),
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StateType] (
    [StateTypeRecId] INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]           VARCHAR (50)       NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted]      BIT                DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StateType_StateTypeRecId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StateTypeRecId] ASC),
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Board] (
    [BoardRecId]     INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TeamRecId]      INT                NOT NULL,
    [Name]           VARCHAR (50)       NOT NULL,
    [IsExternal]     BIT                DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [IsDefault]      BIT                DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted]      BIT                DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateUTC] DATETIMEOFFSET (0) DEFAULT (SYSUTCDATETIME()) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Board_BoardRecId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BoardRecId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Board_TeamRecId] FOREIGN KEY ([TeamRecId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Team] ([TeamRecId]),
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc_TicketType_BoardRecId]
    ON [dbo].[Board]([BoardRecId] ASC);
GO
```

[Simplified Plan using @BoardRecId IN (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(...)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJTkmCVGo) - 40+ sec

[Simplified Plan using @BoardRecId = @BoardRecId](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJagEA4zi) - 7 sec

[Simplified Plan using @BoardRecId = 17 and dbo.Split(...)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryNGSR4fj) - 12 sec

None of these durations are optimal, but the 2nd and 3rd are much better than 40+ sec, so just trying to figure out how to make the best of a bad scenario, and hoping someone can provide a silver bullet here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a query that doesn't improve with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` then you likely have a separate issue from parameter sniffing, that is the root issue. I see some early cases of bad cardinality estimate issues that I think is your root problem.

Specifically I would start looking into your `T.BoardRecId IN (...)` clause. You'd probably be better off materializing the results of the `Split()` function into a temp table first, and then `INNER JOIN`ing to that temp table in your main query instead, to filter on that predicate. The `IN` clause is known to cause cardinality estimate issues, as can subqueries and functions, in `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Don't forget a clustered primary key on the temp table. A table valued parameter is another option, especially if using client apps, this can also have indexes.

Answer (score -2):

replace dbo.split finction with STRING_SPLIT...